# org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in DispatcherServlet with name

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I've created a very basic maven project that implements spring Web MVC.

**web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app> 
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>first</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>first</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

**first-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    ">
    <context:annotation-config />

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.som.controller" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/"></property>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**HelloController.java**

```
package com.som.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HelloController {

    //business logic
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/hello")
    public ModelAndView hello() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("hello");
        
        return modelAndView;
    }
    
}
```

It gives the following error

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet noHandlerFound
WARNING: No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/SpringWebMVC/hello] in DispatcherServlet with name 'first'
```

i have also tried adding

```
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

in first-servlet.xml.
another thing i have tried is using annotating my controller class as

```
@RequestMapping("/")
```

nothing has worked so far.

can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no issue in the code, I tried many versions of springframework and 5.0.2.RELEASE worked for me.